# ip over fiber channel for faster LAN

Tags: fiber, fibre-channel, brocade

Is it possible to set up a fast LAN using HBA's and a fibre switch? I have a brocade 200e and several emulex LP1150 pcie 4GB cards. Information regarding IP over fiber channel is difficult to find. I can run any OS but I prefer windows and if I had to run and older OS virtualized that is okay too.

Comment: some linux maintainer dropped the code because they didn't know the protocol and said "fibrechannel is storage"... so if you go back to very old linux kernels all the code should even be there as opensource. from what I can see these days only AIX supports it any longer. the last standing of 'modern' Unix ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's very possible - I even did it once, only once however - it's all documented in [RFC 4171](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4172) and most if not all HBA manufacturers support it, though obviously not as well as they do 'normal' FC.

By the way I did it with Emulex 1105's on RHEL 5.3x64 and Cisco MDS9509's if that helps.

Comment: Good news indeed Chopper, much appreciated.Can you provide any insight into how you configured the cards and what management driver software you used. Red hat 5 could be an option although I'd prefer windows. Did you see high performance?

Comment: I only did it to get me out of a hole and then only for a few hours so performance wasn't a requirement and I didn't test it either but there's no reason why it shouldn't perform. This was probably about 2009 or so and I found some instruction via an emulex website but I've just tried looking again and nothing leapt out sorry. I'll update this if I find them.

Answer (score 1):

Brocade 200E passes IP traffic just fine.  Have not tried Emulex cards, though.  Qlogic 2300 series (2G) worked well, but 2460 lost packets and nothing could be done about it. AFAIK Qlogic just dropped IP support after 2300.